# jQuery DataTables get <tr> id on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, datatables

I have a datatable with a static column that is populated with a delete button so users can delete entries within the table. However, I am trying to figure out how to get the row's 'id' attribute when clicking the link so that I can include it as a parameter when I send the delete request.

Code:

```
            // Set up our datatable
            var table = jQuery('#service_record').dataTable( {
                "data": t.responseJSON,
                "paging": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "info": false,
                "columns": columns,
                "columnDefs": [ {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<u><a href='#'>Delete</a></u>"
                } ],
                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    jQuery(nRow).attr('id', aData['primary_id_field']);
                    return nRow;
                }
            });

            // Add a listener to respond to the deletion click
            jQuery('#service_record').on('click','.delete', function (e) {

                var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

                // Return
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: On your onclick event, just use `this.id`

Comment: There is no value when using the above method.

Comment: may be `jQuery(this).closest('tr').attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

`aData[]` is an array and expects an integer, not a string.

So instead of `aData['primary_id_field']` you will need to do `aData[0]` or the index of the column of your primary id.  So if the ID is in the first column, it would be `0`, etc.

Comment: The 'id' attribute does not get set this way.